# Keep Buttons location with proportion to Resizing Image

Tags: c#, winforms

I am trying to create a Winforms App and in one of screens, I have an image and some buttons generated at runtime, Now What i want is these buttons should always stay in proportion to the Image

for example Hand1 Button should always remain where Image's Hand1 is

This is my initial Image

[image: Initial Image]

but while resizing the form, it becomes like this

[image]

What I want is these buttons should not change their size and always stay in proportion to the Image.

The ImageSizeMode of the Image is StretchImage and buttons are Not Anchored (otherwise they don't move or start stretch/shrink.

How can i achieve this behavior. ?

Comment: The image is on form or on a picturebox?

Comment: @valter, It is on a picture Box

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a simple, complete solution for a single button:

Note: The scale is calculated relative to the upper, left corner of the control (button). If the scaling needs to be modified such as to the middle or lower/right, then the scaling calculation has to be adjusted. Otherwise the location will not look quite precise and the button will "wander" as the image is resized.

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;

public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    // X, Y scaling variables for btn1
    private float _btn1xScale;
    private float _btn1yScale;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        // The scale is really the % of btn X & Y along image width and height:
        // Calculate X and Y scale from initial location and position in image
        // Has to happen AFTER InitializeComponent is called!
        _btn1xScale = btn1.Location.X / (float)pictureBox1.Width;
        _btn1yScale = btn1.Location.Y / (float)pictureBox1.Height;
    }

    private void pictureBoxResize(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // adjust position based on 
        btn1.Location = new Point(
            (int)(pictureBox1.Width * _btn1xScale), 
            (int)(pictureBox1.Height * _btn1yScale));
    }
}
```

Fancier version:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;

public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private List<ControlScaler> _buttonsToScale = new List<ControlScaler>();

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        // Has to happen AFTER InitializeComponent is called!
        _buttonsToScale.Add(new ControlScaler(btn1, pictureBox1));
        _buttonsToScale.Add(new ControlScaler(btn2, pictureBox1));
    }

    private void pictureBoxResize(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (var control in _buttonsToScale)
            control.AdjustPositionToScale();
    }
}

public class ControlScaler
{
    // X, Y scaling variables
    private float _btn1xScale;
    private float _btn1yScale;

    private Control _scaledControl;
    private readonly Control _scaleTo;

    public ControlScaler(Control scaledControl, Control scaleTo)
    {
        _scaledControl = scaledControl;
        _scaleTo = scaleTo;

        _btn1xScale = scaledControl.Location.X / (float)scaleTo.Width;
        _btn1yScale = scaledControl.Location.Y / (float)scaleTo.Height;
    }

    public void AdjustPositionToScale()
    {
        var newLocation = new Point(
            (int)(_scaleTo.Width * _btn1xScale),
            (int)(_scaleTo.Height * _btn1yScale));

        _scaledControl.Location = newLocation;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Paul, It looks promising now. let me try for multiple buttons now

Comment: @Pankaj: Check out the 2nd version of my code. It allows you to add buttons simply by adding new objects to a list. You won't need to recreate variables etc. It's much cleaner and less error prone!

Comment: @Pankaj: Please also see the added note. The scale is calculated against the upper/left corner of the button(s). If you place the buttons so that the middle or lower/right corners are expected then the calculation needs to be different. You'll be able to figure that out though if you need to.

Comment: foreach (var control in Controls)
            {
                if (control is Button)
                {
                    Button controlButton = (Button) control;
                    _buttonsToScale.Add(new ControlScaler(controlButton, pictureBox1));

Comment: @Pankaj: That will work too, as long as you need all the buttons to participate. :-) If you add OK/Cancel buttons to the form then you'll need to remove them from the collection...

Comment: Thanks @paul, I have edited your answer, While doing it for multiple buttons, I was doing 90% similar to what you have done.

Answer (score 1):

This solution is for *hand1* button. The same logic applies to the other buttons too.

[image]

You want to keep *distances c and d* constant. First measure *a, b, c, d* and:

```
double dblHand1X, dblHand1Y;

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        dblHand1X= (double)b / (double)pictureBox1.Width;
        dblHand1Y= (double)a / (double)pictureBox1.Height;
    }

private void pictureBox1_SizeChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int x, y;

        x = (int)(dblHand1X* (double)pictureBox1.Width) + pictureBox1.Location.X;
        y = (int)(dblHand1Y* (double)pictureBox1.Height) + pictureBox1.Location.Y;

        x -= d;
        y -= c;
        Hand1.Location = new Point(x, y);
    }
```

valter

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to move buttons manually.

1. Choose origins for all buttons. For example, origin the "Hand 1" button is probably `(button.Width / 2; button.Height)` and origin of the "Leg 2" button is `(0; button.Height)`.
2. Calculate and save positions of button origins: `(OriginalX; OriginalY)`.
3. When the form is resized, multiply original positions by scale: `(OriginalX * ScaleX; OriginalY * ScaleY)`. Then set button's position based on new positions of origins: `(OriginalX * ScaleX - OriginX; OriginalY * ScaleY - OriginY)`.

Buttons should be anchored to top left.

Comment: These calculations are not correct. Please see my and @valter's answers for the correct calculations and handling.

Comment: @PaulSasik You've removed a bunch of logic by setting origins to (0;0), added image's offset, and these are the only differences. I'm surprised OP accepted your answer, because buttons will indeed "wander", as you've warned.

Comment: I didn't set the origin to 0, 0. If you run the code you'll see that everything is correct. That's why the answer was accepted. (Where the button actually sticks is up to the user to decide. When I was testing my solution I realized that you'd probably want to set that as a separate property but that is beyond the scope of the OP.) I did remove my down-vote though. After re-reading your answer again I see what you were going for.

Comment: @PaulSasik When I looked at the picture provided by OP, I thought he wants buttons to be "attached" to the lines in the picture. Your solution doesn't provide this feature (Valter's solution does; it's more or less implementation of my solution, just with scale coefficient moved around like you both did). Well, it turned out that you'd read OP's mind correctly and this complexity is unnecessary.

Comment: I'm really not sure exactly what the OP wanted/wants so I implemented the simplest executable solution and added the note about the offset calculation. Also, from the picture I will guess that the OP will need to create anchor points that are set-able. From our discussion I know he did like the code organization that I suggested. Btw, if you implement your pseudocode you'll see that there are variables you're calculating that need not be persisted.